# Filter for Multiple Unique Values in a column

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to be able to create a filtered view based on a list of specified values.

ie in this case I would like to only return the cell that contain the following list of options:

ULPC-XX-1
ULPC-XX-2
ULPC-XX-3
ULPC-XX-4
ULPC-XX-5
ULPC-XX-6
ULPC-XX-7
ULPC-XX-8
ULPC-XX-9
FS-XX-1
BTP-1

Data

[image: Total Data Set]

Desired outcome

[image: Desired Outcome]

Working Spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dAIPftLQ6N0UfrCHYF8brJAtyxmzcPTQw3NzGn4qEro/edit#gid=0

I have tried a few formulas based on RegX but none of them are working

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the values in `A2:B` where the corresponding value in column A starts with `ULPC`, `FS` or `BTP`, you can use:

```cpp
=FILTER(A2:B,REGEXMATCH(A2:A,"^(ULPC|FS|BTP)"))
```

Comment: When I tried this, it filtered out the PSP-23 value but is still also showing the values of BSP-24 & BXR-25